# Cocos2d Touch Bezier (cocos2d V3)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, bezier, chipmunk, curves

There is a way to create chipmunk shape (physic body) from touches (curves)?
I mean, that I can just create some shape from points, but there is a limitation to the number of vertices and the shape of the figure is angular, rather than convex.
I found some info about Bezier, but it is compatible only with old version of cocos2d, but I have to find something for cocos2d V3.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Do you just want to know if there's a limit to the number of vertices that can be used to define a vector outline in cocos2d v3?

Comment: Not exactly, in fact, I need to draw shape on the touches... something like drawing with quadratic bezier curve, but only with cocos2d V3. For example if user draws some circle, I need to know any objects inside and which outside. Maybe there is more simple solution...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
CCDrawNode *node = [CCDrawNode node];
[node drawPolyWithVerts:points count:count fillColor:[CCColor redColor] borderWidth:2 borderColor:[CCColor redColor]];
node.physicsBody = [CCPhysicsBody bodyWithPolylineFromPoints:points count:count cornerRadius:2 looped:YES];
```

Thanks